# cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the associated function `matches`

Tags: rust, full-text-search, rust-diesel

I am trying to using rust diesel full text search, first I added the dependencies:

```
diesel_full_text_search = "1.0.1"
```

then tweak my search code like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::{QueryDsl, RunQueryDsl};
use diesel_full_text_search::{ to_tsvector};
use rust_wheel::config::db::config;
use diesel_full_text_search::TsVectorExtensions;
use crate::model::diesel::dict::dict_models::Article;

mod model;

fn main() {
    use model::diesel::dict::dict_schema::article as article_table;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let mut query = article_table::table.into_boxed::<diesel::pg::Pg>();
    let tsvector = to_tsvector("'dolphinzhcfg', title");
    query = query.filter(&tsvector.matches("经济".parse().unwrap()));
    let query_result = query.load::<Article>(&connection);
}
```

when I compile this code, shows error like this:

```
error[E0284]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:17:36
   |
17 |     query = query.filter(&tsvector.matches("经济".parse().unwrap()));
   |                                    ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the associated function `matches`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `<_ as AsExpression<TsQuery>>::Expression == _`
help: consider specifying the type argument in the method call
   |
17 |     query = query.filter(&tsvector.matches("经济".parse::<F>().unwrap()));
   |                                                        +++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0284`.
error: could not compile `rust-learn` due to previous error
```

what should I do to avoid this problem? BTW, this is the `dict_schema.rs`:

```
table! {
    article (id) {
        id -> Int8,
        user_id -> Int8,
        title -> Varchar,
        author -> Varchar,
        guid -> Varchar,
        created_time -> Int8,
        updated_time -> Int8,
        link -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        sub_source_id -> Int8,
        cover_image -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        channel_reputation -> Int4,
        editor_pick -> Nullable<Int4>,
    }
}
```

and this is the `dict_models.rs`:

```
// Generated by diesel_ext

#![allow(unused)]
#![allow(clippy::all)]

use std::io::Write;
use diesel::deserialize::FromSql;
use diesel::pg::Pg;
use diesel::serialize::{Output, ToSql};
use diesel::sql_types::Jsonb;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use chrono::DateTime;
use chrono::Utc;
use crate::model::diesel::dict::dict_schema::*;

#[derive(Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone)]
#[table_name = "article"]
pub struct Article {
    pub id: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub title: String,
    pub author: String,
    pub guid: String,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub link: Option<String>,
    pub sub_source_id: i64,
    pub cover_image: Option<String>,
    pub channel_reputation: i32,
    pub editor_pick: Option<i32>,
}
```

this is the dependencies of the demo:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "=0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }

serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
serde_derive = "1.0"
# database
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","serde_json"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
jsonwebtoken = "7"
chrono = "0.4"
config = "0.11"
ring = "0.16.20"
md5 = "0.7.0"
data-encoding = "2.3.2"
bigdecimal = "0.3.0"
# reddwarf public component
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git" }
diesel_full_text_search = "1.0.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message already contains all information required to fix this problem:

```
   = note: cannot satisfy `<_ as AsExpression<TsQuery>>::Expression == _`
help: consider specifying the type argument in the method call
   |
17 |     query = query.filter(&tsvector.matches("经济".parse::<F>().unwrap()));
   |                                                        +++++
```

which means you need to specify whatever type `.parse()` should parse into, as rustc cannot infer a type there. The concrete type depends on whatever type is expected by `matches` (checkout the documentation for that).